# Admob and addSubview:

Tags: iphone, admob, addsubview, adbannerview

I just updated the files from admob and now with [bannerView_ addSubview:closeBtn]; I can't see the button anymore.. Someone can help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for `AdMob` ,

in `.h`

```
#import "GADBannerView.h"
```

and declare

```
GADBannerView *AdMob;
```

in `.m`

```
#define AdMob_ID @"yourAdMobId"
```

Then just call this method and provide your x and y

```
-(void)adMobCode
{

    AdMob = [[GADBannerView alloc]
             initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,410,
                                      GAD_SIZE_320x50 .width,
                                      GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

    AdMob.adUnitID = AdMob_ID;
    AdMob.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:AdMob];


    UIButton *Yourbtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, AdMob.frame.origin.y, 30, 30)];
    Yourbtn.tag=2;
    [Yourbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(YourbtnPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    UIImage *PlayBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"];
    [Yourbtn setImage:PlayBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:Yourbtn];


    GADRequest *r = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
    r.testing = YES;
    [AdMob loadRequest:r];
}
```

Comment: I know how to add a banner, the point is that I don't see my UIview over the GADBannerView anymore when I use [bannerView_ addSubview:closeBtn];

Comment: check your internet connection and r.testing=YES;

Comment: the ad is displaying correctly! I want a button OVER the adview !

Comment: so where is the big deal...just add your button over your admobVView

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
[bannerView_ bringSubviewToFront:closeBtn];
```

Comment: I tried that, no results... Very weird. Anyways, I will add the button view in self.view instead.